# Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE throwing InvalidCsrfTokenException when file upload max-file-size is exceeded

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE when I upload files whose size is less than `max-file-size` and `max-request-size` the upload succeeds. When I upload a file larger than these maximums I get an `InvalidCsrfTokenException`.

I have tried to manually add the csrf token to the form but this did not work and I don't want to go down the route of adding the token as a request parameter. I did read something about changing the order of the multipart filter and the Spring security filters so that the csrf token would be available but was unsure how to do this with the latest Boot release. I have also tried to use the `CommonsMultipartResolver` without success.

My `application.yml` contains the following:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      file-size-threshold: 0B
      location: ${java.io.tmpdir}
      max-file-size: 500MB
      max-request-size: 500M
```

and

```
server:
  tomcat:
    max-swallow-size: -1
```

My `AccessDeniedHandler` is catching the `InvalidCsrfTokenException` and redirecting to an error page. I would have expected the csrf token would be available at the appropriate time so that this exception would not occur.

**Update #1**

I set spring.security.filter.order=5 and added the following code but the problem persists:

```
public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
  MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
  multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
  return multipartFilter;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<MultipartFilter> registerMultipartFilter(final MultipartFilter filter) {
  final FilterRegistrationBean<MultipartFilter> reg = new FilterRegistrationBean<MultipartFilter>(filter);
  reg.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
  return reg;
}
```

But the problem still persists.

**Update #2**

I have solved the problem with the following:

Adding the following to my configuration:

```
@Bean
  public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
    MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
    return multipartFilter;
  }

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean<MultipartFilter> registerMultipartFilter(final MultipartFilter filter) {
    final FilterRegistrationBean<MultipartFilter> reg = new FilterRegistrationBean<MultipartFilter>(filter);
    reg.setOrder(0);
    return reg;
  }

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean<HiddenHttpMethodFilter> registerHiddenHttpMethodFilter(final HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) {
    final FilterRegistrationBean<HiddenHttpMethodFilter> reg = new FilterRegistrationBean<HiddenHttpMethodFilter>(filter);
    reg.setOrder(1);
    return reg;
  }
```

Setting the following properties:

```
spring:
  security:
    filter:
      order: 5
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      file-size-threshold: 0B
      location: ${java.io.tmpdir}
      max-file-size: 500MB
      max-request-size: 500MB
      resolve-lazily: true
```

And including the csrf token as a request parameter and catching the resulting MaxUploadSizeExceededException in an exception handler.

I don't like adding the csrf token to the request but this is the only solution I have found.

Comment: You need a `MultipartFilter` to correctly work with Spring Security. This is explained in the reference guide and hasn't changed since, so it should still work the same as it did in older versions of Spring Security.

Comment: Doesn't the spring.servlet.multipart.enabled mentioned above enable this?

Comment: No, that only enables file-uploads it doesn't add the filter.

Comment: I added the MultipartFilter filter but the same issue persists. If the filter didn't already exist wouldn't files less than the max size fail also? They don't.

Comment: Problem is without the filter file uploading is handled in the dispatcher servlet which is behind the security filters. You need to make sure the filter is added BEFORE the security filter.

Comment: After debugging a bit further I have some more information. I added the MultipartFilter it does determine requests less than the max file size are multi-part requests. When I submit files greater than the max file size my access denied handler is immediately executed, the file upload then proceeds, the multi-part filter is triggered but it determines it is not a multi-part request.